# C++ Stack Implementaion HW Error

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, stack

I have experience in C++ but have recently been using python exclusively at work, and I am very rusty. Each file is listed below:

main.cpp

```
#include "stack.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    return 0;
}
```

stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#define NULL 0

template <class elementType>
class stack{

    struct node
    {
        elementType data;
        node* next;
    };

    node* top;

public:

    stack(){
        top = NULL;
    }

    ~stack(){
        node temp = top;
        while (top != NULL){
            top = top->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    void push(elementType x){
        node temp = new node();
        temp.data = x;
        temp.next = top;
        top = temp;
    }

    elementType pop(){
        node temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        return temp;
    }

    bool isEmpty(){
        return top == NULL;
    }
};

#endif //STACK_H
```

makefile

```
a.out : main.o stack.o
    gcc -o a.out main.o stack.o

main.o : main.cpp stack.h 
    gcc -O -c main.cpp

stack.o : stack.h
    gcc -O -c stack.h

clean :
    rm main.o stack.o
```

So, when I `cd` in to the project directory and type `make` i get:

```
gcc -O -c main.cpp
gcc -O -c stack.h
stack.h:7:10: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<’ token
make: *** [stack.o] Error 1
```

I've been searching around for a solution, but as far as I can tell my code is correct. I'm not looking for help with the actual stack implementation, and I realize this code won't actually do anything with an empty main, but I can't seem to fix this compile error.

Comment: Use g++ to compile C++, not gcc.

Comment: @MarkLoeser that should be an answer (because it's the right one) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use g++ to compile C++, not gcc.  Also, you don't need to compile a header.

Comment: Thanks!, I've never actually used a makefile before and it's been awhile since I've even used terminal to compile. Anyway, Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you don't compile header files, only source files.

And you compile C++ with g++, not with gcc.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc -c stack.cpp` would work just fine: gcc recognizes .cpp as an extension for C++, and compiles the file as C++. The problem occurs with `gcc stack.h`; as others have said, don't compile the header. But the reason for the errors is that gcc seems to be treating the file as a C file, not C++ (not unreasonable, but I haven't looked up what it does).

However, when you link, you must use `g++`, or specify the proper C++ runtime library. Easier to use `g++` here.

Oh, and there's an error in `stack.h`. `pop` returns `temp`, but should return `temp.data`.

Also, be careful about defining a macro named `NULL`. It may conflict with the definition in the standard library. Not an issue here, because the code doesn't use any headers from the standard library, but that's artificial.